# Tabbing in Deoplete is Backward

Tags: neovim

When I trigger the autocomplete menu in Deoplete, the tab key's behavior is backward. For example, let's say I pop up an autocompletion drop down.\

[image: Deoplete drop down]

When I hit the tab key, I would expect Neovim to select the first item in the list. Instead, it selects the last.

[image: Deoplete drop down tab]

I'm not sure if this behavior is specific to Deoplete or is a generic issue with Neovim.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick to this one was to remap tab and shift-tab.

```
inoremap <silent><expr><tab> pumvisible() ? "\<c-n>" : "\<tab>"
inoremap <silent><expr><s-tab> pumvisible() ? "\<c-p>" : "\<s-tab>"
```

There are more instructions on how to improve the popup menu in the [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Improve_completion_popup_menu).

Answer (score 8):

In case anybody is using Supertab in addition with deoplete, the following solution is equivalent

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-n>"
```

see for more details the last bullet point at https://github.com/ervandew/supertab#frequently-asked-questions.